# How to correctly create new Object who extended RealmObject with Primary Key?

Tags: android, realm

I'm try use Realm but cought many errors. My answer is:
**How create new Object with Primary key in Realm?**

This is my Object:

```
public class InventoryItem extends RealmObject{

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private int iconId;
    private String name;
    private double weight;

    // ... setters/getters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1.) create managed object with primary key value directly set on creation

```
realm.createObject(InventoryItem.class, primaryKeyValue);
```

2.) create unmanaged object, then set ID,  then copy/insert it to Realm

```
InventoryItem inventoryItem = new InventoryItem();
inventoryItem.setId(primaryKeyValue);
realm.insertOrUpdate(inventoryItem);
```

Of course, any writes to the Realm must be done in a write transaction.

Comment: At some point before the managed RealmObject is created (either via direct creation, or insertion)